# Reinstalled Metamask, Accounts Gone!

Tags: metamask

I've installed metamask on new PC.
Used my 13 words seed phase to recover my account but Accounts didn't recovered.
I've tried all 3 methods that people talked about.
1-I've tried to add 30 accounts from the Create Account button on metamask but the account address I was using didn't created.
2-I've tried Ganache app to create 50 accounts but none of them was my old address.
3-I've used some strange website to create accounts but none of them was my old address.

I know what my old address was, I can see my balance on Bscscan. And I know the exact address (0x...) that should be on metamask but metamask doesn't create that as a sequence.

What should I do now?
Metamask shows warnings in first install "Don't forget your seed phrase" but it never mentions about account recovery.
Seed phrase is useless now, its like empty space password.
What if I transfered all my money to metamask what would happen now? I would be broke.
If I can recover my money from metamask now, never will use it agan.

Comment: Seed phrases are usually 12 or 24 words, perhaps one of the words is the password. For the future make sure the backup works. Also never use the seed phrase on "some strange website".

Comment: How could seed phrase be 13 words? ti should either be 12 or 24 but not 13. Can you share the address of bsc scan?

Answer (score 0):

Did you double-check that you are on the correct network?

By default Metamask connects to the Ethereum Mainnet, but you mentioned your balance on bscscan.com (Binance Smart Chain).

If you just added Metamask to a new PC, maybe you didn't add the BSC network yet.

Comment: The first thing I do after Installing metamask is adding Bsc network.

Comment: Okay then that's not the issue either. I sometimes import accounts instead of adding them. Imported accounts can't be recovered and need to be imported again. If that is not the issue either I am out of ideas.

Answer (score 0):

```
const Web3 = require('web3');
const HDWalletProvider = require('@truffle/hdwallet-provider');
mnemonic = 'enter your seed phrase here'//replace this with your seed phrase
const provider = new HDWalletProvider(mnemonic,'https://bsc-dataseed1.binance.org');
const web3 = new Web3(provider);
const demo = async () => {
    const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();
    console.log (accounts);
}
demo();
```

run this js file after installing npm package @truffle/hdwallet-provider.

Comment: can you give me package log too, i am not good at nodejs :/

Comment: inside a new folder , enter the following commands step by step in terminal
Step 1:npm install @truffle/hdwallet-provider
Step 2:npm install web3
step 3:create a js file with above code in the same folder
step 4:paste your mnemonic in code 
step 4:run the js file using the node cmd (i.e ) node js_file_name.js

Comment: it gave me couple address but none of them was my previous account address. I remember what it was and can see its balance on bscscan, but can't use it.

Comment: code that i shared is similar to how metamask create addresses.so if you have correct seed phrase associated with that account,you can surely recover it

Comment: replace 4th line in above snippet with the following and try again
`    const provider = new HDWalletProvider({
        mnemonic: mnemonic,
        providerOrUrl: "https://bsc-dataseed1.binance.org",
        numberOfAddresses: 100,
        shareNonce: true,
        derivationPath: "m/44'/60'/0'/0/"
      });`

Comment: If you still didn't find your address,change derivation path to `"m/44/714'/0'/0/"`